# TFS Build Server deploys XUnit DLLs

Tags: tfsbuild, xunit.net

My TFS Build deploys the XUnit tests and DLLs to the drop folder. I can't figure out how to restrict the test folder from the deployed exe and binaries/resources.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of TFS you're using. Assuming you're using a recent version, you'll need to customize the workflow (build process template) to perform your desired drop processing logic.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I think you're absolutely correct. It seems a pretty onerous step to take when all you want to do is get rid of non essential deployables.